Percent Completion in Excel
I have a data set where participants entered data into 3 databases, and I want to calculate how much of the study they completed (% completion).  But it gets complicated because participants count as "completed" if they entered into dataset 1 AND dataset 2 OR 2a.
Here's the data:
Dataset
If I only needed % completion for datasets 1 & 2, it would be easy to do
=SUM(B2:J2)/9
However, what I need is something like nested SUMIF statements?
I need to know a percent completion of dataset 1 + dataset 2 or 2a.
So if a participant did not complete dataset 2 @ 4 months, but they DID complete dataset 2a @ 4months, then that counts as completion of dataset 2.
What formula can I use to calculate this?
THANK YOU!!
I tried =SUM(B2:F2) + SUMIF(G2:J2>0, K2:N2)
This doesnt work because I need each cell (G2:J2) > 0, not the total >0 or >4.  I need Excel to look at each individual cell (G2:J2) and if that cell is 0, then look in cells (K2:N2)

Use OR to return 1 if either of the values are 1;
=(SUM(B2:F2)+IF(OR(G2=1,K2=1),1,0)+IF(OR(H2=1,L2=1),1,0)+IF(OR(I2=1,M2=1),1,0)+IF(OR(J2=1,N2=1),1,0))/9


Something like:
=(SUM(B2:F2) + MAX(SUM(G2:J2), SUM(K2:N2)))/9

You could separate it into multiple columns to see the intermediate data and more clearly visualize what it's doing.
Maybe something like this:

O (Dataset 1 score): =SUM(B2:F2)
P (Dataset 2 score): =SUM(G2:J2)
Q (Dataset 2a score): =SUM(K2:N2)
R (Best Dataset 2/2a score): =MAX(P2, Q2)
S (Final score): =(O2 + R2)/9


Thank you, this is definitely on the right track!  It almost works.. it just rounds up a little too much.  For example see Participant ID 11.   The formula should result in 77.7% but your formula gives 80.0%.   Or Participant ID 13 should give 55% but your formula gives 60% completion...

@LeahKaplan where do you get 77.7% for ID 11? Dataset 1 score is 3/5 = 60%. Dataset 2 score is 2/4 = 50%. Dataset 2a score is 4/4 = 100%. so 60% and 100% give 80% overall score, if the two are weighted the same? Ok I think I get that you want it X/9 not added separately. I will have to think more sorry.

@LeahKaplan I've updated the formulas to be total out of 9 rather than separately out of 5 and 4.
